# How do i adjust the breakpoint of my buttons so that they will collapse into a column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

When I decrease my screen size the buttons start to overlap, i was hoping to decrease the breakpoints so that when i decrease the screen size the buttons will collapse. All of my buttons eventually fall into place however i was just wanting them to change as the screen moves. Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>CSS grid example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styles.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu"
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-
awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body class="grid">
<header>Manchester United F.C.</header>
<figure> <img src="images/untlogo.png" style="width:60px;height:60px" >
</figure>
<nav id="menu-nav">
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
<ul>
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="form.html">Form</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
</nav>
<main class="main-home">
<div class="wrapper-home">
<div class="wrapper-button">
<section class="home-left">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/news/first-team">
<article class="ole">
<img src="images/ole.jfif" alt="Ole">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>Team News</h4>
<p>"Ole Gunnar Solskjaer has freshened up his United side to face
Reading in the Emirates FA Cup".
</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</section>
<section class="home-left">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/news/detail/marcus-rashford-learning-
from-solskjaer-and-ronaldo">
<article class="rash">
<img src="images/rash.jfif" alt="Rash">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>Rashfords Breakthrough</h4>
<p>" Why Rashford had shades of Solskjaer and Ronaldo in his game at
Newcastle"
</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</section>
<section class="home-right">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/news/detail/vote-for-man-united-goal- 
of-
the-month-for-december-2018">
<article class="goals">
<img src="images/goals.jfif" alt="goals">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>Goals from the month</h4>
<p>"Watch the eight United goals on our shortlist for December and
cast your vote."
</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</section>
<section class="home-left">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/players-and-staff/first-team">
<article class="players">
<img src="images/team.jpg" alt="Players">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>Player Profiles</h4>
<p>" Click here to look at the offical 2018/19 Manchester United
squad!"
</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</section>
<section class="home-left">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/news/detail/paul-pogba-wins-man-utd-
player-of-the-month-award-for-december-2018">
<article class="potm">
<img src="images/potm.jpg" alt="POTM">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>Player of the Month</h4>
<p>"Fans have picked Paul Pogba as United's top performer of the past
month."
</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</section>
<section class="home-left">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/news/detail/ole-gunnar-solskjaer-on- 
the-
new-year-and-facing-newcastle-united">
<article class="newyear">
<img src="images/newyear.jfif" alt="NewYear">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>Ole's 2019 Plan</h4>
<p>" Ole tells MUTV why he thinks this new year will be enjoyable for
fans"
</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</section>
</section>
<section class="home-left">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/players-and-staff/women">
<article class="women">
<img src="images/women.jfif" alt="Women">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>Womens Team</h4>
<p>"Click here to look at the offical 2018/19 womens Manchester United 
squad!"</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</section>
<section class="home-left">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/players-and-staff/reserves">
<article class="newyear">
<img src="images/u23s.jpg" alt="u23s">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>u23s Team</h4>
<p>"Click here to look at the offical 2018/19 u23s Manchester United 
squad!" 
</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</section>
<section class="home-left">
<a href="https://www.manutd.com/en/players-and-staff/legends">
<article class="legends">
<img src="images/legends.jpg" alt="Legends">
<div class="text-wrap">
<h4>Manchester United Legends</h4>
<p>"Click here to look at all of the past Manchester United legend 
players" 
</p>
</div>
</article>
</a>
</div>
</main>
<nav id="menu-nav2">
</nav>
<script src=".js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

**Style sheet**
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
}
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: Avenir, Helveltica, Arial, san-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.5rem;
color: black;
background-image: url("../images/stad.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}
/* use of * wildcard selector known to be slow so only for demo!  */
body > * {
padding: 1em;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns:repeat (5, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
/*grid-gap: 6px; */
grid-template-areas:
"header  header"
"menu    menu";
}


header {
grid-area: header;
background: darkred;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px darkred;
color: white;
} 
.menu {
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
text-align: center;
}
#menu-nav2 {
grid-area: side;
background-image: url("../images/pogba3.png");
background-size: cover;
box-shadow: -5px -30px 5px 0px darkred;
}
nav {
grid-area: menu;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: darkred;
box-shadow: 4px 0px 5px 0px darkred;
}
nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
nav ul {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
nav li {
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
transition: box-shadow 1s;
}
nav ul li a {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
nav li:hover {
box-shadow: inset 0 -100px 0 0 black;
color: black;
}
nav li:hover a {
color: darkred;
}
figure {
grid-area: figure;
background: darkred;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: center;

}
figure img {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
main {
grid-area: content;
/* increasing the height of one element increases all row heights */
/*height: 25vh;*/
} 
/* Start of form */
.main-form {
width: 100%;
order: 2;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
color: #333;
}
form {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background-color: #C2C2C2;
width: 25%;
height: 600px;
padding: 1%;
box-shadow: 0 5px 20px black;
}
.form {
width: 400px;
}
.form_name {
width: 90%;
}
.email {
width: 90%;
}
.enquiry {
width: 90%;
height: 20%;
margin: 3%;
}
.button_form {
width: 20%;
height: 6%;
cursor: pointer;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
.grid {
grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 10vh 50vh 50vh ;
grid-template-areas:
"figure header  header"
"menu  menu  menu  "
"content content content"
"content content content"
"side side side";

}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.grid {
grid-template-columns: 1fr 9fr 1fr;
/*grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;*/
/*or set the rows to 'view height (vh)'*/
grid-template-rows: 10vh 100vh 1vh;
grid-template-areas:
"figure  header header"
"menu  content side"
"menu  content side";
}
}
nav {
justify-content: flex-start;
}
nav a {
padding: 1em;
}
input {
margin: 3%;
}

/* Home page content */
#searchForm {
height: auto;
width: 50%;
}
.wrapper-home {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}

/* start of home */
ul {
list-style-type: none;
display: table;
width: 90%;
border-spacing: 0 10px;
}
li {
display: table-row;
}
li strong, li .txt, li .langs {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
display: table-cell;
padding-right: 10px;
}
li .txt {
width: 60%;
padding-right: 10px;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
background: #eee;
}
.main-home {
height: 85%;
order: 2;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
}
.wrapper-button {
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.main-home article {
height: 10vmin;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(166, 14, 22, 0.5);
border-bottom: 1vmin solid rgba(166, 14, 22, 1);;
border-radius: 15px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin-right: 100px;
}
.text-wrap {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.text-wrap p {
font-size: 1.5vmin;
}
.text-wrap h4 {
font-size: 2.1vmin;
}
.main-home section {
width: 40vmin;
margin: .5%;
}
.ole img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.ole h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.ole p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.rash img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.rash h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.rash p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.goals img {
height: 100% ;
width: auto;
}
.goals h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.goals p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.players img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.players h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.players p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.potm img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.potm h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.potm p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.newyear img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.newyear h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.newyear p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.prem img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.prem h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.prem p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.women img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.women h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.women p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.u23s img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.u23s h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.u23s p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.legends img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.legends h4 {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.legends p {
color: oldlace;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}

.main-home article:hover {
transform: scale(1.1);
}

.video-wrapper {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.video-wrapper iframe {
padding: 10px;
}
.wiki-header {
color: #DBE3DF;
}

#demo {
background-color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
.txt {
font-size: 2.1vmin;
}

/* End of home page content */
.faq-main {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
}

/* start of faq */
.faq-main h2{
color:darkred;
}
.faq-main p{
color:darkred;
}
.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
adding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
background-color: grey;
}

.accordion:after {
content: '\002B';
color: #777;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

/*end of FAQ*/
/* start of links.html */
.wrapper-contact {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main-contact {
height: 85%;
order: 2;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
}
.main-contact article {
height: 12vmin;
width: 50vmin;
background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
border: 1vmin solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: center;
margin: 5%;
}
.main-contact section {
margin: 2.5%;
}
.facebook img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.facebook h2 {
color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
font-size: 4vmin;
margin: 10%;
}
.gmail img {
height: 50%;
width: auto;
margin-left: 5%;
}
.gmail h2 {
color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
font-size: 2.5vmin;
margin: 10%;
}
.twitter img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
.twitter h2 {
color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
font-size: 3.5vmin;
margin: 10%;
}
.number img {
height: 70%;
width: auto;
margin-left: 5%;
}
.number h2 {
color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
font-size: 4vmin;
margin: 10%;
}
.button-area {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.contact_me img {
height: 70%;
width: auto;
margin-left: 5%;
}
.contact_me h2 {
color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
font-size: 3.5vmin;
margin: 10%;
}
.main-contact article:hover {
transform: scale(1.1);
}
/* end of links.html */

/* footer */
footer {
grid-area: footer;
width: 100%;
height: 5%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
background-color: #333;
order: 3;
}
footer a {
color: #9fff80;
margin-left: 1vmin;
margin-right: 1vmin;
font-size: 2vmin;
}
.icons {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
}
i {
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 2vmin;
}
i p {
display: none;
font-size: 2vmin;
transition: all 2s;
margin-left: 1vmin;
}
i:hover {
color: #9fff80;
}  
i:hover p {
color: #9fff80;
display: inline-block;
}
.cr {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
margin-right: 10vmin;
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do i adjust the breakpoint of my buttons so that they will collapse into a column?

short answer is:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
```

Comment: I really need your stylesheet to give a more personalized answer. Edit your question and add your stylesheet. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, i have updated both my html page and now included my style sheet. Thank you for your help.